# Running Heroku Cedar Locally using Vagrant

Tags: python, ruby, heroku, vagrant, veewee

I would like to develop my Django Heroku app in an environment as close to Heroku's Cedar stack as possible using Vagrant.

The best solution I have found so far for building the mocked up environment is Eric Holmes' excellent https://github.com/ejholmes/vagrant-heroku.  However, this vagrant box currently uses python 2.6.x instead of the Python 2.7.4 my app uses and Heroku defaults to.

The other resource I have found is Heroku's https://github.com/heroku/stack-images.  I have not tried this yet, but it seems to offer a way of creating a cedar stack locally.  It ends up with Python 2.7.2.

***Which of these (or something else) is the best way to go?***  I have a development environment that works now -- and it uses all the same software that Heroku uses (PostgreSQL, Python 2.7.4, etc.) -- but I would like to simulate some of the other aspects of the Heroku environment (memory available, disk space, multi-machine architecture, etc.).

I am leaning towards using Eric Holmes' box and adding Python 2.7.4 per https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu.  I'd offer a patch to Eric's work, but I'm no Rubyist/veewee...

***Update 1:***  Another possible resource: https://github.com/torchbox/vagrant-django-base.

***Update 2:***  I've decided to roll my own by adapting from the above sources and others.  These are the files (Vagrantfile and vagrant_data/install.sh) that I am currently using with some success: https://gist.github.com/ErikEvenson/5801503.  This gets me to Python 2.7.3 and PostgresSQL 9.2.4 on a Ubuntu 12.04 512MB box.

I'd like to split off the database server with a second box and get the app server on Ubuntu 10.04 with Python 2.7.4.

***Update 3:*** My setup has evolved.  This is my current vagrant config: https://gist.github.com/ErikEvenson/9763878.

***Update 4:*** I made several updates to my setup this week.  The latest is at https://gist.github.com/ErikEvenson/9763878.  Of note:

- Use NFS instead of virtualbox folder syncing - huge performance improvement.
- Avoid guest addition bug in current virtualbox version.
- Use newly available Vagrant Cloud for versioned base box.

***Update 5:*** Several updates here -- mostly software versions.  The latest is at https://gist.github.com/ErikEvenson/9763878.  Of note:

- Uses Vagrant 1.6.3
- Uses PostgreSQL 9.3.3
- Uses python 2.7.7 and installs it from source.  python 2.7.3 is retained as the system python.
- Locks down all dependency versions -- especially those installed via apt-get and npm.
- Uses hashicorp/precise64 as a base box.

The file structure to use is something like this:

```
- Project directory
-- vagrant_data
--- db
---- install.sh
---- memcached.conf
---- pg_hba.conf
---- postgresql.conf
---- redis.conf
--- web
---- install.sh
-- Vagrantfile
```

***Update 6:*** Turns vagrant-vbguest on since VirtualBox 4.3.14 fixes some bugs.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have also been looking for a solution....trying yours out now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see my solution to this at https://gist.github.com/ErikEvenson/9763878.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku) which support Heroku buildpacks